# Multitouch on Acer Aspire 4740

Tags: 10.10, multi-touch, acer, aspire

How can I enable multi touch in Ubuntu 10.10 for my Acer Aspire 4740 notebook ?

```
Screen 14.1-inch glossy LED-backlit
1366x768 res 
CPU Intel Core i5-430m 2.26GHz 
RAM 1GB DDR3 
HDD 320GB 
Graphics Onboard Intel GMA HD 
USB Ports 3 
DVD Writer Yes 
Gigabit Ethernet Yes 
Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n 
HDMI/eSATA/FireWire Yes/No/No 
Multicard Reader Yes 
ExpressCard Slot No
```

Comment: Can you give us some more details about your notebook please?

Comment: im using Acer Aspire 4740 , does it depends on whether the laptop supports multitouch ? or depends on the package?

Comment: Add your hardware information to your question so it doesn't get lost in the comments please! See the FAQ: http://askubuntu.com/faq

Comment: You can edit your questions to include this data. Doing so helps create a more rounded question.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Enabling%20True%20Multitouch) describes the necessary steps to enable multi-touch.

I used it as guide and was able to activate multi-touch on my system.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop built with Synaptics touchpad you need to install the synaptics drivers for your environment. To configure, you need gsynaptics configuration tool as well. With tose you can enjoy moultitouch features.

Answer (score 1):

Multitouch and the synaptics driver are installed and ready for use. Have you checked the touchpad settings under System > Preferences > Mouse and the Touchpad tab?

If you are not able to activate multitouch like me:

[image]

you can force the setting by

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=int /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/scroll_method 2
```

If multitouch is not working after this, try a reboot. If it is still not working, try the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# list of synaptics device properties http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html#sect4
# list  current synaptics device properties: xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
#

sleep 2

xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 10

#   Below width 1 finger touch, above width simulate 2 finger touch. - value=pad-pixels
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 7        

#   vertical scrolling, horizontal scrolling - values: 0=disable 1=enable
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 1   

#   vertical, horizontal, corner - values: 0=disable  1=enable
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Edge Scrolling" 0 0 0       

#   stabilize 2 finger actions - value=pad-pixels
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Jumpy Cursor Threshold" 120 

#xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Tap Action" 0 0 0 0 1 2 0
```

If this makes it work, put it in a file, make it executable and add it to your Startup Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following file  with this command

```
sudo gedit /etc/hal/fdi/policy/99-x11-synaptics.fdi
```

And paste this into it.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <deviceinfo version="0.2">
   <device>
      <match key="input.x11_driver" string="synaptics">
         <merge key="input.x11_options.SHMConfig" type="string">on</merge>
         <merge key="input.x11_options.SendCoreEvents" type="string">true</merge>
         <merge key="input.x11_options.VertTwoFingerScroll" type="string">true</merge>
         <merge key="input.x11_options.HorizTwoFingerScroll" type="string">true</merge>
         <merge key="input.x11_options.EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" type="string">35</merge>
         <merge key="input.x11_options.EmulateTwoFingerMinW" type="string">8</merge>
         <merge key="input.x11_options.VertEdgeScroll" type="string">false</merge>
         <merge key="input.x11_options.HorizEdgeScroll" type="string">false</merge>
         <merge key="input.x11_options.JumpyCursorThreshold" type="string">245</merge>
         <merge key="input.x11_options.RBCornerButton" type="string">0</merge>
         <merge key="input.x11_options.TapButton2" type="string">3</merge> <!-- right button -->
         <merge key="input.x11_options.TapButton3" type="string">2</merge> <!-- not functional -->
         <merge key="input.x11_options.FingerHigh" type="string">41</merge>
      </match>
   </device>
</deviceinfo>
```

---